# AngularJS/HTML - Cannot execute links to same page after introducing interceptor

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Would like to check what is the issue caused to my `<a href>` links when after I introduced an interceptor to my angular app and it has cause the links to not reload when it is on the same page? below is how i introduce my interceptor to add jwt's Authentication token to my web service requests header.

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$localStorage', '$location', function ($q, $localStorage, $location) {
       return {
           'request': function (config) {
               config.headers = config.headers || {};
               if ($localStorage.jwtToken) {
                   config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.jwtToken;
               }
               return config;
           },
           'responseError': function (response) {
               if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {

               }
               return $q.reject(response);
           }
       };
    }]);
}]);
```

Noted that the presentation site and the business logic processing part are both independently separated and do not rely on each other. Which means that the presentation site is responsible to load the javascripts and HTML codes while the scripts are the one that is responsible to request data from the server. Authentication are done via JWT therefore I use the interceptor to inject the JWT related headers to every RESTful requests.

PHP => (*renders HTML template*) + (*data from Angular*) <= Angular => (*send request to server get data*)

Using the code above i was able to complete the JWT authentication but it causes all the `<a href>` links on the presentation page to not reload if it is in the same page. For example I have 3 items in my menu (Home, Page1, Page2). When I'm in `Home` and if I click on the `Home` link, it suppose to reload the page (like F5) but nothing happens. I would need to navigate away from the page then only i am able to click on the link.

What have i done wrong here?

**Update 1**: Question from @Sanjeev: *How are you handling routing in you app, are you using ng-router module or custom ui-router module ? Can you add the routing code as well.*

Noted that at this moment all routes are within the HTML itself using  links. The javascripts do not handle any routes. Its responsibility is to GET and POST data.

**Update 2**: Added [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4GhbFWlrOVENZVof4KAb?p=preview) link. Note that i would suggest you to try both commenting and uncommenting the entire interceptor section to see the difference when clicking the link. Follow these instruction below and you will recreate the scenario i mentioned.

1. Load and run the plunker file
2. On the top right corner, click on "Launch the preview in a separate window"
3. Copy the URL in the window and replace it in the  section in line 25. The url should look something like ***run.plnkr.co/somerandomkeys***+
4. Close the separate window and try clicking the link in the menubar.

When commenting the said section, notices that the page will load (acts as a refresh) but when you uncomment the section the link will not work anymore. Some sort of same page detection thing is blocking the action.

Comment: How are you handling routing in you app, are you using ng-router module or custom ui-router module ? Can you add the routing code as well.

Comment: @Sanjeev at this moment all routes are within the HTML itself using <a href> links. The javascripts do not handle any routes. Its responsibility is to GET and POST data.

Comment: So i think you are doing server side redirection, is it a single page app ? Can you add a response callback in interceptor & check if it is coming there when you click on anchor?

Comment: @Sanjeev i managed to recreate the scenario. Pls see update 2 and i also included instructions to recreate the scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution :**

Analysis:  I ran your demo and understood the issue you were highlighting, actually the issue is not related to interceptors at all. Interceptors get called only when you make http requests using $http service.

In Angular apps the anchor tag behavior changes the moment you inject '$location' service in your app, you have injected '$location' service in your interceptor module (although i don't see it being used). So this solves the mystery why you start getting anchor issue when you add interceptor :)

In your example the anchor has same link as the current location so Angular is preventing the default behavior of anchor tag and clicking anchor does not reload your page.

You can solve it be multiple ways:

1. Don't inject '$location' service if you are not using it, if you can't remove it then go for solution  2 or 3.
2. Add attribute target="_self"  or target="_blank" as per your case, this    will solve your issue without requiring any Js code change. I tested this fix  with your code and it worked for me.
3. Add a ng-click handler on anchors and change window.location in
   it, or better create a directive for anchors and check if href is
   same as current location then force page reload using location.reload()
4. If you decide to use angular routing which is great feature of Angular JS then use $route.reload() method